# Comparar variables en Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, variables

Necesito hacer una comparación entre 2 variables:

Controlador:

```
$files = \File::files('images');

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $info[] = pathinfo($file);
}

$books = File::where('status', 1)->select('name')->get();

return view('cataloged.read', compact(['info','books']));
```

En mi vista *Blade* tengo algo como esto:

```
@foreach($books as $book)
    @foreach($info as $file)
        @if($book->name == $file['basename'])
            <p>Book</p>
        @else
            <p>No Book</p> 
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

En mi base de datos, solo tengo 4 registros:

```
@if($book->name == $file['basename'])
       <p>Book</p>
@endif
```

> Book Book Book Book

Pero cuando le aumento `@else` me devuelve siete (`7`) No Book por cada **Book** excepto el último que solo devuelve *Book*.

> Book - No book 7 veces 
>   Book - No book 7 veces 
>  
>   Book - No book 7 veces  
>   Book

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Bueno como comente tengo 4 registros en mi bd y estoy leyendo 7 archivos de un directorio, por lo tanto espero 4 book y 3 No book, pero si hago un nuevo registro, el resultado debería de ser 5 book y 2 No book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en el comentario en el cual explicas que deseas obtener como resultado siete líneas de las cuales:

- 4 son "Book"
- 3 son "No Book"

Esto significa que debes iterar por los siete archivos (para obtener siete resultados) almacenados en `$info`y dentro de este ciclo, iterar por los cuatro "libros" almacenados en `$books`, a menos que tengas un parámetro distinto para ubicar más fácilmente los libros sin un bucle:

```
@foreach ($info as $file)

    @php $hasBook = false; @endphp

    @foreach ($books as $book)

        @if ($book->name == $file['basename'])
            <p>Book</p>

            @php $hasBook = true; @endphp
        @endif


    @endforeach

    @if (!$hasBook)
        <p>No Book</p>
    @endif

@endforeach
```

El problema que tiene esta solución es que estamos definiendo una variable `$hasBook` y estamos además cambiando su valor, y esto no debería ser responsabilidad de la Vista. En mi opinión deberías revisar los valores que obtienes en `$info` y en `$book` y encontrar/establecer una relación más completa en el controlador o en un servicio (o como tengas estructurada tu aplicación).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero me devuelve lo mismo que a mi 
Bookx4 No book x 7

Comment: Había cometido un pequeño error al momento de copiar la respuesta, por favor intenta de nuevo con la modificación que le hice.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no entiendo muy bien el alcance de ambito de la funcion compact, pero tu variable $info es local a la sentencia foreach, creo que primero deberias declararla fuera de este antes de hacer la asignacion.

Tambien podrias usar el metodo with, de los Response, ya que compact es propio de php, mientras que with pertenece al framework y tiene mejor integracion con este. Seria algo como:

```
return view('cataloged.read')->with(['info' => $info, 'books' => $books]);
```

Comment: No hay ninguna diferencia al momento de usar `with` o `compact`, de hecho Jeffrey way de laracasts prefiere usar `compact`.

Comment: Tambien lo intente con with amigo :(